# Tmux reset scrollback on keypress

Tags: unix, tmux, scrolling

When you've scrolled back within tmux (using the mouse via `mode-mouse`), is there a way to make tmux reset the scroll when you press a key (unless that key is a tmux command)?

This seems to be default behaviour in a lot of terminal emulators, so that you can see the command you're editing once you start typing.

Comment: I've just found out you can press `q` to quickly exit scrolling mode, which is a decent halfway solution.

Comment: is valid answer your own question and mark it.

Comment: It's not a full solution because you have to press a specific key, instead of just starting to type your command.

Comment: Keep an open mind - The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just trying to help. http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask